# Why override abstract method parameter type is any in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract method(type: string): void
}

class Child extends Base {
    method(type) {
        console.log(type)
    }
}
```

Error:
[image: Compile error]

Why override method parameters is any? I defined the parameter type in abstract class, Why not use it?

Answer (score 1):

> I defined the parameter type in abstract class, Why not use it?

Because it's not implemented in the compiler. [There's a GitHub issue for it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911).

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't infer the types for inheritance / implements

## Why

Cause it breaks real world code. It's wants you to be explicit.